# Is there a repository with different ssl related files for testing purpose?

Tags: tls, certificates, openssl, key

I am looking for a repository with various different ssl related files like certificates (PEM, DER, p7c, ...), certificate requests, keys, ... for testing purpose.

It would also be of interest to get files like .sst, .stl, .pvk

Is there a repository with files like this?

Answer (score 2):

## Frankencerts?

There was some research on mutated/misencoded "FrankenCerts" ("Frankenstein Certificates").

- The paper is here: [*Using Frankencerts for Automated Adversarial Testing of Certificate Validation in SSL/TLS Implementations*](http://stap.sjtu.edu.cn/%7Echenyt/mucert.html)
- And also: *"A package containing 357 mucerts that can trigger validation discrepancies among OpenSSL, PolarSSL, and GnuTLS can be downloaded [here](http://stap.sjtu.edu.cn/%7Echenyt/test_certificates.zip)"*

## OpenSSL Test cases?

OpenSSL has [several test certificates on board](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/tree/master/test/certs) as part of internal test harness. (And I assume that all other TLS libraries have a similar stash of certs.)

Comment: Thank you. It seems that at the link you provided, there are only ".pem" files. I am especially looking for different types of ssl related file (pkcs12, pkcs7, ...)